# I'm getting a type error but not sure why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't work out why this code is returning a type error

```
if response == "1":
   return print(" You've selected the Bundle Package! Please schedule a home visit and our technician will come and set up your new service.") + home_visit("new install")
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str

Is it because I am trying to call a function as well as printing a statement?

Comment: That's because `print` doesn't return a string, it just prints the result to stdout (and return `None`). Therefore when you try to do `print("s")+"s"` you actually do `None + "s"` which leads to this error.

Comment: Apparently `home_visit("new install")` returns `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a misconception that you have. Returning print() does not return the string containing it. If you want to still print the string inside, then call the function, and return the printed string to wherever you called it, you can probably do it this way:

```
if response == "1":
   # this is the string you want
   whatIWantToPrint = " You've selected the Bundle Package! Please schedule a home visit and our technician will come and set up your new service."
   # this is where you print it
   print(whatIWantToPrint)
   # this is where you call the function
   home_visit("new install")
   # this is where you return the string you printed
   return whatIWantToPrint
```

Comment: Thanks man, this works a charm thanks for explaining it. This also helped me realise i didn't actually need to return anything the code worked how i wanted it without, i think that was another misconception i had, i thought that an if statement always needed a return value.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because print doesn't return anything. It just prints.
if you wanna return print + home_visit then:

```
return f"You've selected the Bundle Package! Please schedule a home visit and our technician will come and set up your new service.{home_visit('new install')}"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect, could you explain how this works? im a little confused how i can replicate this in my own code. what does the f mean and does using the {} separate the function from the string?

Comment: This is a shortcut for string formatting. "Hello, {}. You are {}.".format(name, age) can be replaced just by f"Hello, {name}. You are {age}." Literally, Python executes code that in {} so you can use it to evaluate any variable or execute any code.

Answer (score 0):

The error says you are trying to concat the return of print which is NoneType and a string.
You should print then return the string.
Here is an example:

```
if response == "1":
    print(" You've selected the Bundle Package! Please schedule a home visit and our technician will come and set up your new service.")
    return home_visit("new install")
```